# Curl Post Json data not being read in Python Django

Tags: python, json, curl

Am using curl exe in windows, to communicate with my Django backend.

Following is the command am using.

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{\"uid\":12,\"token\":\"asdert\"}" http://localhost:8000/restapi/v1/foo/
```

Now this give the data in wrong format. i.e. in the view the post is showing this data 
print request.POST

```
{"{\"uid\":12,\"access_token\":\"asdert\"}": [""]}
```

What is the correct way to post json data ?

**Edit:**

I have tried several other methods for e.g.
I am trying to communiate with my rest api using  http://slumber.in/.

Even here am getting the same result as above.

```
import slumber
api = slumber.API("http://localhost/restapi/v1/"
api.foo.post({"uid":"100"})
```

Excerpts from the view
     print request.POST

```
 {u'{"uid": "100"}': [u'']}
```

P.S. -     `curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "uid=12&token=asdert" http://localhost:8000/restapi/v1/foo/`

This works. But this is not Json format.

Comment: No if you print the request.POST in the view it gives a dicitionary with key as the data above and a an empty value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried your command with http://httpbin.org/post and it worked fine.

Now, your problem is that you should access the incoming JSON data from

```
request.raw_post_data
```

instead of `request.POST`.

(Or if you are using Django 1.4+, use `request.body` instead as `request.raw_post_data` is being deprecated)

---

Detailed code should be something like this:

```
import json

if request.method == "POST":
    data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
    print data
```

Comment: It is giving an error that the object is not Json. i.e. No Json object could be decoded

Comment: @AkashDeshpande can you try print request.raw_post_data?

Comment: '{uid:1234,access_token:aaa}'

Comment: @AkashDeshpande Interesting, what if you simply use `curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"uid":12,"token":"asdert"}' http://localhost:8000/restapi/v1/foo/` instead without the windows-specific hack?

Comment: Same as above 

'{uid:100,access_token:AAA}'


I used this command though

curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"uid":100,"access_token":"AAA"}' http://localhost:8000/restapi/v1/icrave/

Comment: @AkashDeshpande I tried the code on a Django app and it worked perfectly. So now I am wondering if it's other things that are causing the problem: 1. if you are using Django 1.4, can you try use `request.body` instead of `request.raw_post_data`? 2. it might be `curl` that's buggy on windows, can you try using WFetch or Firebug to send the JSON instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18358/discussion-between-kay-zhu-and-akash-deshpande)